# How to Moq Entity Framework SqlQuery calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq, dbcontext

I've been able to mock `DbSet`'s from entity framework with Moq using this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx).

However, I would now like to know how I could mock the call to SqlQuery. Not sure if this is possible or how as it relies on the mocked db context knowing what "query" is being called.

Below is what I am trying to mock.

```
var myObjects = DbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<MyObject>("exec [dbo].[my_sproc] {0}", "some_value")
    .ToList();
```

I currently haven't tried anything as did not know how to start mocking this example.

The mocking of the `DbSet` is below and to re-iterate, I can correctly mock returning a `DbSet` of `MyObject`'s but now am trying to mock a SqlQuery that returns a list of `MyObject`'s.

```
var dbContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
dbContext.Setup(m => m.MyObjects).Returns(mockObjects.Object);

dbContext.Setup(m => m.Database.SqlQuery... something along these lines
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`Database.SqlQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is not marked as virtual, but [`Set<T>.SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is marked as virtual.

Based on [`Database.SqlQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) documentation

> The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the
>   type of object returned is an entity type. Use the ['SqlQuery(String,
>   Object[])'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method to return entities that are tracked by the
>   context.

and [`Set<T>.SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) documentation

> By default, the entities returned are tracked by the context; this can
>   be changed by calling AsNoTracking on the DbRawSqlQuery returned.

then the `Database.SqlQuery<T>(String, Object[])` should be equivalent with `Set<T>.SqlQuery(String, Object[]).AsNoTracking()` (only if `T` is EF entity, not a DTO / VM).

So if you can replace the implementation into:

```
var myObjects = DbContext
    .Set<MyObject>()
    .SqlQuery("exec [dbo].[my_sproc] {0}", "some_value")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

you can mock it as follow

```
var list = new[] 
{ 
    new MyObject { Property = "some_value" },
    new MyObject { Property = "some_value" },
    new MyObject { Property = "another_value" }
};

var setMock = new Mock<DbSet<MyObject>>();
setMock.Setup(m => m.SqlQuery(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
    .Returns<string, object[]>((sql, param) => 
    {
        // Filters by property.
        var filteredList = param.Length == 1 
            ? list.Where(x => x.Property == param[0] as string) 
            : list;
        var sqlQueryMock = new Mock<DbSqlQuery<MyObject>>();
        sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.AsNoTracking())
            .Returns(sqlQueryMock.Object);
        sqlQueryMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(filteredList.GetEnumerator());
        return sqlQueryMock.Object;
    });

var contextMock = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
contextMock.Setup(m => m.Set<MyObject>()).Returns(setMock.Object);
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  For me, this was preferable to abstracting away the querying logic into a helper, like in the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 13):

You can add a virtual method to your database context that you can override in  unit tests:

```
public partial class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows you to override queries that use the Database property
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<T> SqlQueryVirtual<T>(string query)
    {
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The [`Database`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) property and [`SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method are not marked as `virtual` so they [can't be mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462669/1698557) (using Moq; you could use a [different library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) that can account for this but that may be more inertia than you'd like).

You'd need to use some sort of abstraction to get around this, such as by wrapping the entire query of the database in a helper class:

```
public interface IQueryHelper
{
    IList<MyObject> DoYourQuery(string value);
}

public class QueryHelper : IQueryHelper
{
    readonly MyDbContext myDbContext;

    public QueryHelper(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        this.myDbContext = myDbContext;
    }

    public IList<MyObject> DoYourQuery(string value)
    {
        return myDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>("exec [dbo].[my_sproc] {0}", value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now the method you are testing becomes:

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    var myObjects = queryHelper.DoYourQuery("some_value");
}
```

Then you'd inject the `IQueryHelper` in the constructor of the class you're testing and mock that.

You're going to be missing test coverage on `DoYourQuery`, but the now the query is [so simple there are obviously no deficiencies](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/C._A._R._Hoare).

Answer (score 1):

Should anyone come across this.  I solved this with a few approaches.  Just another way to address this.

1. My context is abstracted through an interface.  I only need a few of the methods:

   ```
   public interface IDatabaseContext
   {
       DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
       DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class;
       int SaveChanges();
       Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
       void AddOrUpdateEntity<TEntity>(params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class;
   ```

   }
2. All of my database access is through async methods. Which brings up a whole new set of problems when trying to mock it.  Fortunately - it has been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943328/ef6-mocking-derived-dbsets)  The exception you get is related to the missing mock for IDbAsyncEnumerable.  Using the solution provided - I just extended it a bit more so that I had a helper to return a Mock> object that mocked all of the properties expected.

   ```
   public static Mock<DbSqlQuery<TEntity>> CreateDbSqlQuery<TEntity>(IList<TEntity> data)
       where TEntity : class, new()
   {
       var source = data.AsQueryable();
       var mock = new Mock<DbSqlQuery<TEntity>>() {CallBase = true};
       mock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(source.Expression);
       mock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(source.ElementType);
       mock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(source.GetEnumerator());
       mock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>(source.Provider));
       mock.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator()).Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity>(data.GetEnumerator()));
       mock.As<IDbSet<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Create()).Returns(new TEntity());
       mock.As<IDbSet<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Returns<TEntity>(i => { data.Add(i); return i; });
       mock.As<IDbSet<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Returns<TEntity>(i => { data.Remove(i); return i; });
       return mock;
   }
   ```
3. Finally - using the solution provided by @Yulium Chandra - my testing of raw SQL with mocked context looks like:

   ```
       public Mock<DbSet<TestModel>> MockDbSet { get; }

       ....

       MockDbSet.Setup(x => x.SqlQuery(It.IsAny<string>))
             .Returns<string,object[]>
             ((sql, param) => 
             {
                   var sqlQueryMock = MockHelper.CreateDbSqlQuery(Models);

                   sqlQueryMock.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking())
                     .Returns(sqlQueryMock.Object);

                   return sqlQueryMock.Object;
               });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I did a variation on @Patrick Quirk's answer which is working well for me, where I pass the context into the method itself.  My interface:

```
public interface ISqlQueryHelper<T, in TU> where T : class where TU : DbContext
    {
        Task<IList<T>> Execute(FormattableString value, TU context);
    }
```

the implementation:

```
public class SqlQueryHelper<T,TU> : ISqlQueryHelper<T,TU> where T : class 
                                                            where TU : DbContext
    {
        public async Task<IList<T>> Execute(FormattableString value, TU context)
        {
            return await context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(value).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

... wiring up the dependency injection in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<ISqlQueryHelper<UserDto,UserContext>, SqlQueryHelper<UserDto,UserContext>>();
```

then finally a call to it:

```
FormattableString query = $"EXECUTE [dbo].[GetTechLeadForSpecifiedUser] @userId = {userId}";

            var techLeads = (await _sqlQueryHelper.Execute(query, _context)).ToList();
```