# Moq Entity Frameworks ExecuteSQLCommand

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I've read that when using moq you cannot mock a non-virtual function. I've also read that this should be possible now..  Is that true? 
If so, then I'd like to mock the following query:

```
DatabaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updateQuery, newValue);
```

I'm overriding the Context in my test as so

```
DAL.Context.DatabaseContext = mockContext.Object;
```

I've tried this setup, but it seems the query stills goes agains my regular db

```
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<AppSalesAndResult>()).Returns(mockBudgetData.Object);
```

Any ideas, could perhaps the executesqlcommand be replaced with something else so that the row above would catch any udpates to the set? I use executesqlcommand due to performance reasons when updating multiple rows at once. Regular EF is too slow

UPDATE:

Reading the following post, [How to Moq Entity Framework SqlQuery calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014969/how-to-moq-entity-framework-sqlquery-calls) I wonder if a similar implementation would work for ExecuteSQLCommand...

Comment: Can you post a MVP (minimal viable prototype) of your problem so we can help with this?

Answer (score 13):

What I have done to being able to Mock ExecuteSqlCommand, which is not possible to do in DataBase class, was to create the same method in my DbContext inheritance but this time virtual, and call the Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
    }
    public virtual int ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(transactionalBehavior, sql, parameters);
    }
```

Then I changed my business code to call this created method (Not Database method):

```
DatabaseContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(updateQuery, newValue);
```

Then, it works

Comment: Nice, had to do the same thing with CanConnect().

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to mock `ExecuteSqlCommand`. It is however not straightforward.

Being an extension method you have to mock the internals. It ends up creating a `RawSqlCommand` and invoking `ExecuteNonQuery` on an `IRelationalCommand`. It gets further complicated as the extension method creates new objects to do the actual work, as well as there being is no interface for `RawSqlCommand` or `DatabaseFacade`, you've got to mock the concrete classes.

I ended up writing [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) as there isn't anything else around that can do all the mocks (FromSql, ExecuteSqlCommand, DbQuery, the relational stuff that the in-memory provider can't do). Save yourself some time as the mocks are involved, I certainly would have used an existing package if there was one when I was looking.

If you do want to roll your own the mock set up for `ExecuteSqlCommand`/`ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` looks like the following:

```
var relationalCommandMock = new Mock<IRelationalCommand>();
relationalCommandMock
    .Setup(m => m.ExecuteNonQuery(It.IsAny<IRelationalConnection>(), It.IsAny<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>>()))
    .Returns((IRelationalConnection providedConnection, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> providedParameterValues) => executeSqlCommandResult);
relationalCommandMock
    .Setup(m => m.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(It.IsAny<IRelationalConnection>(), It.IsAny<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns((IRelationalConnection providedConnection, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> providedParameterValues, CancellationToken providedCancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(executeSqlCommandResult));
var relationalCommand = relationalCommandMock.Object;

var rawSqlCommandMock = new Mock<RawSqlCommand>(MockBehavior.Strict, relationalCommand, new Dictionary<string, object>());
rawSqlCommandMock.Setup(m => m.RelationalCommand).Returns(relationalCommand);
rawSqlCommandMock.Setup(m => m.ParameterValues).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object>());
var rawSqlCommand = rawSqlCommandMock.Object;

var rawSqlCommandBuilderMock = new Mock<IRawSqlCommandBuilder>();

rawSqlCommandBuilderMock
    .Setup(m => m.Build(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<object>>()))
    .Returns((string providedSql, IEnumerable<object> providedParameters) => rawSqlCommand);

var rawSqlCommandBuilder = rawSqlCommandBuilderMock.Object;

var serviceProviderMock = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
serviceProviderMock.Setup(m => m.GetService(It.Is<Type>(t => t == typeof(IConcurrencyDetector)))).Returns((Type providedType) => Mock.Of<IConcurrencyDetector>());
serviceProviderMock.Setup(m => m.GetService(It.Is<Type>(t => t == typeof(IRawSqlCommandBuilder)))).Returns((Type providedType) => rawSqlCommandBuilder);
serviceProviderMock.Setup(m => m.GetService(It.Is<Type>(t => t == typeof(IRelationalConnection)))).Returns((Type providedType) => Mock.Of<IRelationalConnection>());
var serviceProvider = serviceProviderMock.Object;

var databaseFacadeMock = new Mock<DatabaseFacade>(MockBehavior.Strict, mockedDbContext);
databaseFacadeMock.As<IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>>().Setup(m => m.Instance).Returns(serviceProvider);
var databaseFacade = databaseFacadeMock.Object;

Mock.Get(mockedDbContext).Setup(m => m.Database).Returns(databaseFacade);
```

`executeSqlCommandResult` is the expected integer to return. You could use a callback to apply any operation said sql command performs on your data source.

*Note that I am passing the mocked db context to the database facade mock constructor then performing another Moq set up on the mocked database, I get away with this as I have already performed a set up on the DbContext Database property as part of mocking the db context. I have observed test success with an inline new instance so I don't think it matters, just in my case I didn't want to spin up another instance.*