# Mock MyDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nsubstitute

i need to mock EF for my unit tests. Many tests are already working, but now i'm in a test that needs to mock the Database-Object in my DbContext, because the MyDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand is called.

Like this (almost 3 years ago and unanswered)
[Moq Entity Frameworks ExecuteSQLCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664431/moq-entity-frameworks-executesqlcommand)

But with NSubstitue.

UPDATE:

I'm using the identity framework. So if nsubstitute is not throwing an exception itself, i get an exception from the identity framework

```
Castle.Proxies.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Castle.Proxies.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

I tried all the following:

```
DBContextMock.When(x => { var get = x.Database; }).DoNotCallBase();
DBContextMock.When(x => { var get = x.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE"); }).DoNotCallBase();
DBContextMock.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE").ReturnsForAnyArgs(0);
```

Any ideas to mock the Database object?

Comment: I've got the same problem.   Anyone have any ideas?  I did a lot of searching and can only find a package called Effort to help with this.  I can't believe this isn't a common problem though