# Mocking EF's ExecuteSqlCommand using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm using Entity framework core. I was referring to one of the code suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515103/9766215

```
public void SaveOrUpdate(MyEntity entity)
{
    var sql =  @"MERGE INTO MyEntity
                USING 
                (
                   SELECT   @id as Id
                            @myField AS MyField
                ) AS entity
                ON  MyEntity.Id = entity.Id
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE 
                    SET     Id = @id
                            MyField = @myField
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (Id, MyField)
                    VALUES (@Id, @myField);"

    object[] parameters = {
        new SqlParameter("@id", entity.Id),
        new SqlParameter("@myField", entity.myField)
    };
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
}
```

I need to mock ExecuteSqlCommand but this extension method is not allowed to be overridden by Moq setup. I don't want to mock the whole method `SaveOrUpdate`. 
Please suggest if there's any way to mock or setup it for unit testing using any Database context methods. I'm using `UseInMemoryDatabase` for unit testing database context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like the suggestion here:[Moq Entity Frameworks ExecuteSQLCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664431/moq-entity-frameworks-executesqlcommand). That is not really mocking the entire function but the `ExecuteSqlCommand`, by adding a wrapper in your context:

So in your context class

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
    }
    public virtual int ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(transactionalBehavior, sql, parameters);
    }

    // The rest of the implementation
```

So now you can mock the context, and since the functions are vitrual, you can mock them too. You will only need to change your code like this:

```
public void SaveOrUpdate(MyEntity entity)
{
    var sql =  @"MERGE INTO MyEntity
                USING 
                (
                   SELECT   @id as Id
                            @myField AS MyField
                ) AS entity
                ON  MyEntity.Id = entity.Id
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE 
                    SET     Id = @id
                            MyField = @myField
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (Id, MyField)
                    VALUES (@Id, @myField);"

    object[] parameters = {
        new SqlParameter("@id", entity.Id),
        new SqlParameter("@myField", entity.myField)
    };
    context.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to mock your method not the EF core implementation. You can make your mehtod virtual and mock it's implementation with Moq:

```
public virtual void SaveOrUpdate(MyEntity entity)
{
    var sql =  @"MERGE INTO MyEntity
                USING 
                (
                   SELECT   @id as Id
                            @myField AS MyField
                ) AS entity
                ON  MyEntity.Id = entity.Id
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE 
                    SET     Id = @id
                            MyField = @myField
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (Id, MyField)
                    VALUES (@Id, @myField);"

    object[] parameters = {
        new SqlParameter("@id", entity.Id),
        new SqlParameter("@myField", entity.myField)
    };
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
}
```

and then mock the implementation of this method.

Have a look at the following posts :

https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/26014969/how-to-moq-entity-framework-sqlquery-calls

[How to Moq Entity Framework SqlQuery calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014969/how-to-moq-entity-framework-sqlquery-calls)