# How could I Mock the FromSql() method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq

I was wondering is there any way other than building a wrapper for mocking the `FromSql`? I know this method is static, but since they added things like `AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase` to entity framework core, I thought there might be a solution for this too, I use EF Core 1.0.1 in my project.

My end goal is to test this method:

```
public List<Models.ClosestLocation> Handle(ClosestLocationsQuery message)
{
    return _context.ClosestLocations.FromSql(
        "EXEC GetClosestLocations {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
        message.LocationQuery.Latitude,
        message.LocationQuery.Longitude,
        message.LocationQuery.MaxRecordsToReturn ?? 10,
        message.LocationQuery.Distance ?? 10
    ).ToList();
}
```

I want to ensure that my query is handled with the same object that I passed into it, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017936/1650277) in entity framework 6 I could do something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void HandleInvokesGetClosestLocationsWithCorrectData()
{
    var message = new ClosestLocationsQuery
    {
        LocationQuery =
            new LocationQuery {Distance = 1, Latitude = 1.165, Longitude = 1.546, MaxRecordsToReturn = 1}
    };

    var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<Models.ClosestLocation>>();

    dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.FromSql(It.IsAny<string>(), message))
        .Returns(It.IsAny<IQueryable<Models.ClosestLocation>>());

    var contextMock = new Mock<AllReadyContext>();

    contextMock.Setup(c => c.Set<Models.ClosestLocation>()).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

    var sut = new ClosestLocationsQueryHandler(contextMock.Object);
    var results = sut.Handle(message);

    contextMock.Verify(x => x.ClosestLocations.FromSql(It.IsAny<string>(), It.Is<ClosestLocationsQuery>(y =>
        y.LocationQuery.Distance == message.LocationQuery.Distance &&
        y.LocationQuery.Latitude == message.LocationQuery.Latitude &&
        y.LocationQuery.Longitude == message.LocationQuery.Longitude &&
        y.LocationQuery.MaxRecordsToReturn == message.LocationQuery.MaxRecordsToReturn)));
}
```

But unlike `SqlQuery<T>` in EF 6, the `FromSql<T>` in EF Core is static extension method, I'm asking this question because I think I might approach this problem from the wrong angle or there might be a better alternative than a wrapper, I'd appreciate any thought on this.

Comment: internally the EF core [FromSql extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1fa247b038927a7d7438f666dc11253f64e0432d/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/RelationalQueryableExtensions.cs) is making a call to `CreateQuery` on the `IQueriable.Provider` you could look at mocking that to achieve what you want.

Comment: Did you find any solution for mocking FromSql?

Comment: @YawarMurtaza No, there is Philippe answer, but I haven't try it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also fell into the same situation and answer given by Philippe helped but it the main method was throwing `System.ArgumentNullException`.

From [this link](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/11/unit-testing-entity-framework-core-stored-procedures/), I was finally able to write some unit tests...

Here is my class under test:

```
public class HolidayDataAccess : IHolidayDataAccess
{
    private readonly IHolidayDataContext holDataContext;

    public HolidayDataAccess(IHolidayDataContext holDataContext)
    {
        this.holDataContext = holDataContext;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<HolidayDate>> GetHolidayDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (this.holDataContext)
        {
            IList<HolidayDate> dates = await holDataContext.Dates.FromSql($"[dba].[usp_GetHolidayDates] @StartDate = {startDate}, @EndDate = {endDate}").AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            return dates;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetHolidayDates_Should_Only_Return_The_Dates_Within_Given_Range()
{
    // Arrange.

        SpAsyncEnumerableQueryable<HolidayDate> dates = new SpAsyncEnumerableQueryable<HolidayDate>();
        dates.Add(new HolidayDate() { Date = new DateTime(2018, 05, 01) });
        dates.Add(new HolidayDate() { Date = new DateTime(2018, 07, 01) });
        dates.Add(new HolidayDate() { Date = new DateTime(2018, 04, 01) });
        dates.Add(new HolidayDate() { Date = new DateTime(2019, 03, 01) });
        dates.Add(new HolidayDate() { Date = new DateTime(2019, 02, 15) });


    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HolidayDataContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .Options;

    HolidayDataContext context = new HolidayDataContext(options);

    context.Dates = context.Dates.MockFromSql(dates);

    HolidayDataAccess dataAccess = new HolidayDataAccess(context);

    //Act.
    IEnumerable<HolidayDate> resutlDates = await dataAccess.GetHolidayDates(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), new DateTime(2018, 05, 31));

    // Assert.

    Assert.AreEqual(resutlDates.Any(d => d.Date != new DateTime(2019, 03, 01)), true);
    Assert.AreEqual(resutlDates.Any(d => d.Date != new DateTime(2019, 02, 15)), true);

    // we do not need to call this becuase we are using a using block for the context...
    //context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
}
```

To use `UseInMemoryDatabase` you need to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` package from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory)
The helper classes are here:

```
public class SpAsyncEnumerableQueryable<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> listOfSpReocrds;

    public Type ElementType => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IQueryProvider Provider => new Mock<IQueryProvider>().Object;

    Expression IQueryable.Expression => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public SpAsyncEnumerableQueryable()
    {
        this.listOfSpReocrds = new List<T>();
    }        

    public void Add(T spItem) // this is new method added to allow xxx.Add(new T) style of adding sp records...
    {
        this.listOfSpReocrds.Add(spItem);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
       return this.listOfSpReocrds.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    IAsyncEnumerator<T> IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return listOfSpReocrds.ToAsyncEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

...and the Db extensions class that contains the mock of FromSql method..

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static DbSet<T> MockFromSql<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, SpAsyncEnumerableQueryable<T> spItems) where T : class
    {
        var queryProviderMock = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
        queryProviderMock.Setup(p => p.CreateQuery<T>(It.IsAny<MethodCallExpression>()))
            .Returns<MethodCallExpression>(x => spItems);

        var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .SetupGet(q => q.Provider)
            .Returns(() => queryProviderMock.Object);

        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(q => q.Expression)
            .Returns(Expression.Constant(dbSetMock.Object));
        return dbSetMock.Object;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Edits**: refactored SpAsyncEnumerableQueryable class to have Add method. Got rid of parameterised construction that took array of T. Implemented `IQueryProvider Provider => new Mock<IQueryProvider>().Object;` to support `.AsNoTracking()`. Calling the ToList asynchronously.

Comment: Why is `MockFromSql<T>` an extension method? It doesn't appear to actually do anything to or with `dbSet`.

Comment: I tried this with a collection and works fine, but trying to mock a method that has FirstOrDefaultAsync  throws an exception with the message The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the code in [`FromSql<T>`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/master/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/RelationalQueryableExtensions.cs), you can see that it makes a call to `source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>`. This is what you have to mock.

In your case, I think you can work it out with something like that:

```
var mockProvider = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
mockProvider.Setup(s => s.CreateQuery(It.IsAny<MethodCallExpression>()))
    .Returns(null as IQueryable);
var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<AllReady.Models.ClosestLocation>>();
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<AllReady.Models.ClosestLocation>>()
    .Setup(s => s.Provider)
    .Returns(mockProvider.Object);
var t = mockDbSet.Object;
context.ClosestLocations = mockDbSet.Object;

var sut = new ClosestLocationsQueryHandler(context);
var results = sut.Handle(message);
```

Not sure how you can `Verify` on a `MethodCallExpression` afterwards, but I suppose that would be possible. Alternatively, there might be a way to check the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread is old; however if anyone else is looking;
It's possible to perform a Moq verify on a from sql invocation, you've got to do it against the query provider.

```
var providerMock = Mock.Get(((IQueryable<TestEntity>) mockedDbContext.Set<TestEntity>()).Provider);
providerMock.Verify(m => m.CreateQuery<TestEntity>(It.IsAny<MethodCallExpression>()), Times.Once);
```

Same methodology applies to NSub as well.

The method call expression verification can be fine tuned to match on sql and parameters, it contains the sql (RawSqlString) and the parameters (IEnumerable) as constant expressions.

```
var mceRawSqlString = (RawSqlString) ((ConstantExpression) mce.Arguments[1]).Value;
var mceParameters = (object[]) ((ConstantExpression) mce.Arguments[2]).Value
```

where mce is the `MethodCallExpression` fed to `CreateQuery`.

I've done a bit of MCE deconstruction in my project [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) to support FromSql mocking; I farm out the actual matching to supporting methods as it gets a bit hairy.

```
queryProviderMock.Setup(m => m.CreateQuery<T>(It.Is<MethodCallExpression>(mce => SpecifiedParametersMatchMethodCallExpression(mce, sqlToMatchAgainst, parametersToMatchAgainst))))
```