# Hot to Mock a DbQuery used in a join

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I am using a View in EntityFramework Core through something like

```
modelBuilder.Query<DeviceHierarchy>().ToView("DeviceHierarchy");
```

I tried to use the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726638/how-could-i-mock-the-fromsql-method) to mock the view.

The view is used in a join like this

```
Context.Devices.Where(...).Join(Context.DeviceHierarchy, ...)
```

but I got an exception and can not figure out what's the problem

```
at System.Linq.Lookup`2.CreateForJoin(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.JoinIterator[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](IEnumerable`1 outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Func`2 outerKeySelector, Func`2 innerKeySelector, Func`3 resultSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)+MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncEnumerableAdapter`1.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
```

Can a view be mocked using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory package?

Comment: Are you working with repository pattern?

Comment: Since I am using a join then no. Also I do not see the relevance since I would still want a join to be done on the database and not in memory.