# MSTest v2 and The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, entity-framework-core, mstest

I am trying to create unit tests(MSTest v2) for a DAL library(EF core)

**DataService**

```
    public IQueryable<BalanceDTO> GetCollection()
    {
        var entities = dbContext.Balance;
        var dtos = mapper.Map<ICollection<BalanceDTO>>(entities).ToList();
        dtos.ForEach(_d =>
        {
            _d.MonthSort = _d.Date.Month;
            _d.MonthName = (new DateTimeFormatInfo()).GetMonthName(_d.MonthSort);
        });
        return dtos.AsQueryable();
    }

    public async Task<IList<BalanceDTO>> GetBalancesByYear(int year)
    {
        return await GetCollection().Where(_d => _d.Date.Year == year).OrderBy(_d => _d.MonthSort).ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Test**

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow(2020, 2019)]
    public void GetBalancesByYearTest(int found, int notfound)
    {
        var _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AssemblyProperties.AssemblyDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AccountManagerContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AccountManagerLocalDB"));

        var balanceDataService = new BalanceDataService(optionsBuilder);
        var elementsFound = balanceDataService.GetBalancesByYear(found);
        var elementsNotFound = balanceDataService.GetBalancesByYear(notfound);

        Assert.IsNotNull(balanceDataService);
        Assert.IsTrue(elementsFound.Result.Count > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(elementsNotFound.Result.Count == 0);
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<AccountManager.DAL.DTO.BalanceDTO>. 
Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

I have found a couple of link but couldn't figure out how to resolve this.

[ToArrayAsync() throws "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743165/toarrayasync-throws-the-source-iqueryable-doesnt-implement-iasyncenumerable)

[How to overcome the IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider while Mocking the FromSql() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824737/how-to-overcome-the-iqueryable-doesnt-implement-iasyncqueryprovider-while-mocki/57825026)

Any idea about how to create tests for my DataService methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution.
If anyone sees an error or something to be improved, I do appreciate any recommendations.

```
    public IQueryable<BalanceDTO> GetCollection()
    {
        var entities = dbContext.Balance;
        var dtos = mapper.Map<ICollection<BalanceDTO>>(entities);
        foreach(var _d in dtos)
        {
            _d.MonthSort = _d.Date.Month;
            _d.MonthName = (new DateTimeFormatInfo()).GetMonthName(_d.MonthSort);
        };
        return dtos.AsQueryable();
    }

    public async Task<IList<BalanceDTO>> GetBalancesByYear(int year)
    {
        var entities = dbContext.Balance.Where(_d => _d.Date.Year == year).OrderBy(_d => _d.Date);
        var balanceDTOs = Task<IList<BalanceDTO>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var dtos = mapper.Map<IList<BalanceDTO>>(entities);

            foreach (var _d in dtos)
            {
                _d.MonthSort = _d.Date.Month;
                _d.MonthName = (new DateTimeFormatInfo()).GetMonthName(_d.MonthSort);
            };
            return dtos;
        });

        return await balanceDTOs;
    }
```

I've modified `GetBalancesByYear` so it doesn't make use of the `GetCollection` as it would not be performant if it has to collect the complete collection of elements and transform them into DTO just before filtering what it's not needed.

I am quite confused on who to create correctly the async methods for my DAL when they need to return DTO and not just Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework works with `DbSet`s, that are more than queryables.

You can [use the In-Memory provider for your tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory), or [mock the `Dbset`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349351/how-to-add-an-item-to-a-mock-dbset-using-moq).

Comment: Thanks, but  isn't that for xUnit?

Comment: I see. Still this doesn't fix the issue I am facing with the methods. `GetBalancesByYear` throws the same exception. I cannot use directly use DbSet because I need to adapt the entities to the corresponding `DTO`

Comment: Does `GetBalancesByYear` work outside your unit tests? `AsQueryable` outside of testing is, usually, a code smell. Whatever you think it's making,

Comment: So far... yes, or at least I think so. When I call the `GetColletion()` method I see in the SQL profiler `SELECT [b].[BalanceID], [b].[Date], [b].[DateClosed], [b].[FinalAmount], [b].[InitialAmount], [b].[PercentVariation], [b].[Variation]
FROM [Balance] AS [b]` What would you recommend as solution to use DbSet with the AutoMapper ?

Comment: It was been years since I've used AutoMapper, but I recall it doing a good job of rewriting the query. Check their documentation.