# Mocking SqlQuery with where condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, moq, dbcontext

I've been following the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014969/how-to-moq-entity-framework-sqlquery-calls) about how to mock sqlquery call, but when I try to replace the query string with a where condition, it return the all of the object in the list instead of the expected filtered list, is it not possible to filter the object by its property name?

```
var myObjects = _context
                    .Set<myObject>()
                    .SqlQuery("select * myObject where id = '1'")
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: are you using MVC 5 or core?

Comment: @YatFeiLeong I am using asp.net MVC 5

Comment: ur sql query doesn't look correct though