# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

My original search was "mocking dbsets does not return all entries" and I found an entry that appeared to describe my problem.

[DbSet mock, no results while calling ToList secondly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460893/dbset-mock-no-results-while-calling-tolist-secondly)

However, the solution uses the following syntax

```
q.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns( () => queryableData.GetEnumerator() );
```

which gives me this compiler error
"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' because it is not a delegate type"

Other searches suggest I add using statements which I already have:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
```

Here's my method (I'm using RhinoMocks and the other poster was using Moq but I don't think that's my problem)

```
private static IDbSet<T> GetDbSetTestDouble<T>(List<T> data) where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = data.AsQueryable();

        IDbSet<T> dbSet = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbSet<T>, IQueryable>();

        dbSet.Stub(m => m.Provider).Return(queryable.Provider);
        dbSet.Stub(m => m.Expression).Return(queryable.Expression);
        dbSet.Stub(m => m.ElementType).Return(queryable.ElementType);

        // Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' because it is not a delegate type
        dbSet.Stub(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Return( () => queryable.GetEnumerator());
    }
```

Comment: I think you simply need to remove the lambda portion (e.g. the `() =>`) and just return tell it to return the result of `queryableData.GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 3):

As the error is trying to tell you, `.Return` takes a value to return (in this case, an `IEnumerator`), not a lambda.

Comment: i.e. drop the "() =>" in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Generic Enumeration here. Please refer to the below link.

[EF6 Mocking derived DbSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943328/ef6-mocking-derived-dbsets)